# Is it possible to use wsdl web service in iphone?

Tags: iphone, sdk

Hello every one.....

```
 I am using wsdl web service in my project.I don't know how to use it.But from the wsdl2objc i generate the wsdl into objective c form.And after that i implement it into my project.In my wsdl there are many methods like getCountryList,getCityList,getCompanyContact....etc.Now i have a problem...i mean i fetched getCityList but not all city is shown in my city list.
Now i don't know what is the problem in my code.
```

Please tell me some suggestions....if you understand my problem...My code is..

```
- (SoapRequest*) getScanCustomerCompanies: (id <SoapDelegate>) handler machineId: (NSString*) machineId loc: (NSString*) loc cat: (int) cat pausefollow:(int)pausefollow favorite:(int)favorite activeontop:(int)activeontop nationwide:(int)nationwide orderby:(int)orderby
{
    return [self getScanCustomerCompanies: handler action: nil machineId: machineId loc: loc cat: cat pausefollow:pausefollow favorite:favorite activeontop:activeontop nationwide:nationwide orderby:orderby];
}

- (SoapRequest*) getScanCustomerCompanies: (id) _target action: (SEL) _action machineId: (NSString*) machineId loc: (NSString*) loc cat: (int) cat pausefollow:(int)pausefollow favorite:(int)favorite activeontop:(int)activeontop nationwide:(int)nationwide orderby:(int)orderby
{
    NSMutableArray* _params = [NSMutableArray array];

    [_params addObject: [[[SoapParameter alloc] initWithValue: machineId forName: @"machineId"] autorelease]];
    [_params addObject: [[[SoapParameter alloc] initWithValue: loc forName: @"loc"] autorelease]];
    [_params addObject: [[[SoapParameter alloc] initWithValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: cat] forName: @"cat"] autorelease]];
    [_params addObject: [[[SoapParameter alloc] initWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:pausefollow] forName:@"pausefollow"]autorelease]];
    [_params addObject: [[[SoapParameter alloc] initWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:favorite] forName:@"favorite"]autorelease]];
    [_params addObject: [[[SoapParameter alloc] initWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:activeontop] forName:@"activeontop"]autorelease]];
    [_params addObject: [[[SoapParameter alloc] initWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:nationwide] forName:@"nationwide"]autorelease]];
    [_params addObject: [[[SoapParameter alloc] initWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:orderby] forName:@"orderby"]autorelease]];

    NSString* _envelope = [Soap createEnvelope: @"getScanCustomerCompanies" forNamespace: self.namespace withParameters: _params withHeaders: self.headers];
    SoapRequest* _request = [SoapRequest create: _target action: _action service: self soapAction: @"urn:abc#getScanCustomerCompanies" postData: _envelope deserializeTo: [[SDZscanCustomerCompanies alloc] autorelease]];
    [_request send];
    return _request;
}
```

Thanks.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the tool available online here:

http://sudzc.com/

I always use this service whenever I have SOAP request to handle.

Comment: i am also using this.But i have problem in fetching the data.My all cities not fetching in my list.I mean i have 30cities on web server.But only 21 cities return to me...Tell me what i do....?

Comment: Check the XML it may be broken or the nodes are not proper. If neither the case then go ahead and generate the classes again and use them.

Comment: I did both i check the XML its working properly and i also tried to generate classes angain.But i dont know what happen....Do you have some link or code example.....?

Comment: dump it...just to parse do not use it. Here is another solution and should be useful: <http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/>

Comment: @KPT....thanks for help.I am checking and learning this link..Is this link help me in using wsdl?

Comment: There is option to accept and upvote also if the answer is helpful.

Comment: @kpt....i have only 1 reputation....so i can't vote...i think u can understand...sorry for that...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iOS can consume WebServices including WSDL style.
Nobody probably knows where is your problem because you have not posted any code yet.

EDIT:

Cudzc generator makes a class which is named according wsdl name and prefix that you specified on the web site. In this class I had to change namespace and url according to the soap standards.

```
- (id) init
    {
        if(self = [super init])
        {
            self.serviceUrl = @"https://isir.justice.cz:8443/isir_ws/services/IsirPub001";
            self.namespace = @"urn:IsirPub001/types";
            self.headers = nil;
            self.logging = YES;
        }
        return self;
    }
```

Basically I recommend you to take SOAPUI, test the service on your machine and compare to the request that is generating by your code.

Comment: Have you tried to call the web services by SOAP UI or something similar to test the source? Just guessing that the problem could be on the source side.

Comment: i just use the built in code from wsdl2objc and use NSXMLParsing in that code......The soap call is inside the generated code.But it doesn't show me all list of companies.....Can you tell me what i do now?

Comment: @vanya....do you know how to use wsdl in iphone....can you tell me some link or any example for wsdl style

Comment: Yes I do, I use for WSDL another code generator http://www.sudzc.com/ , I my case I just littlebit changed the url request and all working fine.

Comment: @vanya...i am also using sudzc code generator.It is wsdl2objc cod generator...Plz tell me what changes u did in url request..plz